# No input file specified Error with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

This is the .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And i get no file input specified this is where i get the error http://bluntstresser.com/user/register

If any one can please help me that would be great be at this for weeks

Comment: did you already resolve the issue? the link you posted opens fine for me :)